# Rewrite .htaccess all files except

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have the following in my `.htaccess` file which rewrites all files names so I can limit access to my media.

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
#RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, I would like specific files to be ignored. For example: `^wp-content/uploads/2022/12/image-26.png` and `^wp-content/uploads/2022/11/horse47.jpg`

How can I update my rewrite rules to skip those specific files (and others).

I tried rewriting the original files after the above (3rd line) but does not work.

---

Solved thank you. Mr White

Comment: Those two lines are currently _commented out_?

Comment: yes, sorry. I keep them commented out as I tried o figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried rewriting the original files **after** the above (3rd line) but does not work.

"After" is too late, the request will have already been rewritten to your script! You would need to rewrite the files **before** your existing rule.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2022/12/image-26\.png$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2022/11/horse47\.jpg$ - [L]

# Existing directives go here...
```

The `L` flag prevents the following rules from being processed.

Don't forget to backslash-escape the literal dot and include the end-of-string anchor on the regex.

Alternatively, add exceptions (conditions) to the existing rule. For example:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^2022/12/image-26\.png$
RewriteCond $1 !^2022/11/horse47\.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*) dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `!` prefix negates the expression. So it is successful when it does not match.